# Python 3: Importing file containing variables to be used as constants

Tags: python, constants

I want to use a config.py file in which I will be declaring some constants to be used in mainFile.py.

I'll be defining these "constant variables" using Capital letters.
I want to make it easier to configure the mainFile.py parameters by defining the constants only in config.py.

Ofcourse, in mainFile.py, the values of these constant are by no means altered.

So, my question is :
If in mainFile.py I use "From config.py import *", are the "constant variables" defined in config.py used as global variables in mainFile.py?
E.g. inn functions defined within mainFile.py, do I need to re-define these variables as global in order to use them?

Comment: Why not to just try it yourself? Your constants will be in global scope

Comment: You should have a look over [configParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) if you want to consider storing configuration in a .config/properties/ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write `import config`, and all of your constants will be accessible to your code in `mainFile.py`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. As already pointed out by @Josh, in `config.py` you name your variables, such as `m=10`, `t=52`, and so on. Then on `mainFile.py` you `import config` and access your variables as `config.m` that will result in `10`. Like:

`y = config.m`
`y = 10`

2. The second option is a bit longer. You create a function such as

`def m():
     m = 10
     return m`

Then on `mainFile.py` you `import config` and access the variable as `config.m()` that will yield `10`. Like

```
z = config.m()
z = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`global` is required if you are modifying the imported variable in some case and you need to reflect that value on all other places where the variable is being accessed.

since you are just reading the value of the imported variable here, `global` is no required. also inside functions if any variable is read first it searches on local scope then on global scope. So no `global` required inside function for reading purpose.